# How can we prove this statement?

Tags: definition, angle

Okay, so I was reading the definition of **Angles**. It says the following:

> Draw an imaginary circle around the vertex.  The angle is the portion of the imaginary circle captured (subtended) by the rays.  No matter how small or large you draw your circle the fraction of the circle captured (subtended) by the rays would be the same.  For example, if the angle is measured using degrees, and the angle shown is $50$ degrees, then no matter how large or small you draw your imaginary circle around the vertex, then you get $50$ degrees out of $360$ degrees (whole circle).  Using distance to measure the same thing is arc measure, which measures a specific arc a part of a specific circle drawn a specific distance from the vertex.  Draw a small circle, get a smaller distance.  Draw a larger circle and the distance gets greater.  These are two different measurements and two different things.

---

> No matter how small or large you draw your circle the fraction of the circle captured (subtended) by the rays would be the same.

1. How to prove this statement?
2. Are angles really defined this way?

Comment: This is a very intiuitive definition and should be supported by visuals. Although there may be some formal definition but Angle is just a concept... Gradually the concept matters more than the definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{Area of Circle}=\pi r^2$$
$$\text{Area of Sector}=\pi r^2\cdot\frac{\theta}{360}$$
$$\text{Fraction of Circle}=\frac{\text{Area of Sector}}{\text{Area of Circle}}=\frac{\theta}{360}$$
As you can see, the fraction of the circle is only dependent on the angle and independent of the radius of the circle. Hence Proved.

Comment: I think the formula you used is incorrect. "Area of circle".

Comment: Just one question *(might be a silly one)*: What's the proof of the "area of a sector". I know that it is derived from the unitary method but I am not sure why the unitary method works.

Comment: Why would the unitary method not work?

Comment: I know it would work due to symmetries. Still, I am not able to get it.